# How to completely delete entity description in the Core Data Model editor in Xcode 4.4.1

Tags: xcode, core-data

How to completely delete entity description in the Core Data Model editor in Xcode 4.4.1 ?
There is only "Add entity" button exist in the user interface.

Answer (score 47):

1. Highlight the Entity that you want to delete.
2. Press the backspace (delete) key.

Comment: lol. upvoted :) Not sure the question is relevant on stackoverflow tho.

Comment: Don't laugh. Sometimes the delete mysteriously just stops working. Just had it happen to me again.

Comment: crashes on me every time i try and delete the entity

Comment: Hint: be careful with combination `command+delete`, it deletes the entire data model.

Comment: When doing this, can any problems be caused? And will all the data in that entity you backspace be deleted?

Comment: This comment is relevant and needed. One can easily highlight the entity to delete in Xcode 12 and press Command+Delete and delete the entire model. This answered saved me.

Answer (score 9):

In case it **crashes** when you try to delete it. Try this:

1. right click on the `.xcdatamodel` file
2. click "show in finder"
3. right click and "show package contents"
4. open file "contents" which is XML and delete the entity you don't want any more.

Answer (score 6):

I've got a crash when trying to delete Entity by highlighting and pressing backspace.

Solution in my case was to open `.xcodeproj` instead of `.xcworkspace` just for this operation and Entity was removed with success.

Comment: Worked for me. Thank you!