# How to completely delete entity description in the Core Data Model editor in XCode 9?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data

The old way was to select the Entity, press backspace key.

This no longer works. Instead it crashes Xcode. Tested on a new, empty, default project from Apple's template, with no changes other than creating some Entities and then (trying to) delete them.

Is there another way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Here's what ended up working for me:

1. Close Xcode (it crashes if you change things while it's open)
2. Find the project folder, look in there for the "something.xcdatamodeld" thing
3. It's actually a magic folder, so Alt + RMB = Select ShowPackageContents
4. Open the relevant datamodel file in TextEdit or similar
5. ...its in a very simplistic XML format, so it's trivial to edit.
6. Delete the entries, and search/replace for their names and make sure you delete any relationships that pointed to them

Comment: The various solutions are described in [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11950850/how-to-completely-delete-entity-description-in-the-core-data-model-editor-in-xco).

Comment: The top-voted answer on that question is incorrect. The lower-voted answers that are correct are less-complete than my answer here *and* they were all answered a year or more after my answer. Referring people to a less-complete, less-accurate, newer answer is ... not helpful?

Comment: The top answer there worked fine for me. The second highest answer there is a more concise version of yours. Yes, seems worth it to me.

Comment: Your comment has added nothing (except to necromance a 5 year old question with no activity). There are lots of unanswered questions on the site crying out for responses...